# Does WlanFreeMemory() work with NULL

Tags: c, windows, winapi, wlanapi

In looking at `wlanapi` examples I recently saw the following pattern a few times:

```
if (ptr) {
    WlanFreeMemory(ptr);
}
```

I wrote a small program to call `WlanFreeMemory` on a null pointer, and it executed without any errors (that I could observe), but I'm still not convinced.

I first had assumed this was a common issue of a programmer adding an unnecessary `NULL` check before delete, free, etc.  However, I don't see anything on [the msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to confirm that the function is safe to call with NULL.  Perhaps someone more experienced in windows programming knows the answer to this?

Comment: Even if it executes successfully *now* without any errors, there's no contract for that, so it may very well change its behavior (e.g. to an access violation) in a future version of Windows.  And then Raymond will have to add a compatibility shim for your app because you relied on undocumented behavior.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I could believe that somewhere microsoft has said "any of our functions that free memory accept NULL and perform no operation with it" or something like that.  I don't know my way around the windows api well enough to find it if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer may not be null. If null were allowed, then the pointer would have been annotated as `_In_opt_` rather than `_In_`.